# ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 300, 300, 1) but got array with shape (1, 260, 300, 1)

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run the following code : The code loads an existing model "model_6cat.h5" and runs a prediction using same.

```
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy
import cv2
import os


dataColor = (0,255,0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fx, fy, fh = 10, 50, 45
takingData = 0
className = 'NONE'
count = 0
showMask = 0


classes = 'NONE ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE'.split()


def initClass(name):
    global className, count
    className = name
    os.system('mkdir -p data/%s' % name)
    count = len(os.listdir('data/%s' % name))


def binaryMask(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7,7), 3)
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
    ret, new = cv2.threshold(img, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return new


def main():
    global font, size, fx, fy, fh
    global takingData, dataColor
    global className, count
    global showMask

    model = load_model('model_6cat.h5')

    x0, y0, width = 200, 220, 300

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cv2.namedWindow('Original', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    while True:
        # Get camera frame
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) # mirror
        window = copy.deepcopy(frame)
        cv2.rectangle(window, (x0,y0), (x0+width-1,y0+width-1), dataColor, 12)

        # draw text
        if takingData:
            dataColor = (0,250,0)
            cv2.putText(window, 'Data Taking: ON', (fx,fy), font, 1.2, dataColor, 2, 1)
        else:
            dataColor = (0,0,250)
            cv2.putText(window, 'Data Taking: OFF', (fx,fy), font, 1.2, dataColor, 2, 1)
        cv2.putText(window, 'Class Name: %s (%d)' % (className, count), (fx,fy+fh), font, 1.0, (245,210,65), 2, 1)

        # get region of interest
        roi = frame[y0:y0+width,x0:x0+width]
        roi = binaryMask(roi)

        # apply processed roi in frame
        if showMask:
            window[y0:y0+width,x0:x0+width] = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        # take data or apply predictions on ROI
        if takingData:
             cv2.imwrite('data/{0}/{0}_{1}.png'.format(className, count), roi)
             count += 1
        else:
            img = np.float32(roi)/255.
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
            pred = classes[np.argmax(model.predict(img)[0])]
            cv2.putText(window, 'Prediction: %s' % (pred), (fx,fy+2*fh), font, 1.0, (245,210,65), 2, 1)
            # use below for demoing purposes
            #cv2.putText(window, 'Prediction: %s' % (pred), (x0,y0-25), font, 1.0, (255,0,0), 2, 1)

        # show the window
        cv2.imshow('Original', window)

        # Keyboard inputs
        key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff

        # use q key to close the program
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

        # Toggle data taking
        elif key == ord('s'):
            takingData = not takingData

        elif key == ord('b'):
            showMask = not showMask

        # Toggle class
        elif key == ord('0'):  initClass('NONE')
        elif key == ord('`'):  initClass('NONE') # because 0 is on other side of keyboard
        elif key == ord('1'):  initClass('ONE')
        elif key == ord('2'):  initClass('TWO')
        elif key == ord('3'):  initClass('THREE')
        elif key == ord('4'):  initClass('FOUR')
        elif key == ord('5'):  initClass('FIVE')

        # adjust the size of window
        #elif key == ord('z'):
        #    width = width - 5
        #elif key == ord('a'):
        #    width = width + 5

        # adjust the position of window
        elif key == ord('i'):
            y0 = max((y0 - 5, 0))
        elif key == ord('k'):
            y0 = min((y0 + 5, window.shape[0]-width))
        elif key == ord('j'):
            x0 = max((x0 - 5, 0))
        elif key == ord('l'):
            x0 = min((x0 + 5, window.shape[1]-width))

    cam.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initClass('NONE')
    main()
```

and because the network wanted to have input_shape as 300x300 but my model is 260x300, i am getting the error message "ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 300, 300, 1) but got array with shape (1, 260, 300, 1)" during the runtime.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "application.py", line 84, in main
    pred = classes[np.argmax(model.predict(img)[0])]
  File "/home/pankaj/vev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 913, in predict
    return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/pankaj/vev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1695, in predict
    check_batch_axis=False)
  File "/home/pankaj/vev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 144, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 300, 300, 1) but got array with shape (1, 260, 300, 1)
```

is there any quickfix for this issue? or do i have to re-create the model?

Comment: Which exact script in that repo?? And where exactly the error occurs?? Try to be more specific, otherwise nobody can be of any help...

Comment: Try improving your question, editing it, instead of putting links on comments. Try posting an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have to resize your image to the correct size...

Comment: How do i resize the images within my model?

Comment: You must resize images outside the model. The model can only handle images in the specific size it was built to work with. Somewhere in the code of `roi` or `img` they're getting a different dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Your model expects images 300x300 and you're giving it an image 260x300.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your code:-

```
x0, y0, width = 200, 220, 300
```

to

```
x0, y0, width = 200, 180, 300
```

and see the result.